# How does SqlParameter know the type

Tags: .net, ado.net, sqlparameter

I was wondering how does `SqlParameter` know the type when it is not specified?

For example, when instantiating a parameter object you don't need to specify the DB Type. Somehow when the command is executed .net handles this for you. Behind the scenes is there some sort of conversion taking place? Is there a cost when you do / don't specify the type explicitly?

Comment: I don't know about any cost in terms of performance, but there are cases when the *guessing* of the parameter type goes haywire and you end up with bad and unexpected results. My recommendation: *always* explicitly define your types - then it's clear and no guessing is involved

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a cost when you do / don't specify the type explicitly?

Yes, and the cost can be *huge*. It has nothing to do with client side cast, but everything with server side execution. You should read [Under the Table - How Data Access Code Affects Database Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx). Some problems that can occur are:

- use of NVARCHAR type can negate your indexes. If you use `SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@someparam", "somestring")` the resulted parameter is `NVARCHAR` type. If your query has a clause `WHERE somecolumn = @someparam` and `somecolumn` is of type VARCHAR and indexed then the type mismatch will prevent the index use.
- parameter length plan cache polution. If you use `SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@someparam", "somestring")` it will result in a query that has a parameter type `NVARCHAR(10)` and when you use `SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@someparam", "anotherstring")` it will result in a query that has a parameter of type `NVARCHAR(13)` and this will be considered a *different* query, and produce a different plan. In time you can pollute the server plan cache with hundreds of plans, one for each possible length of the parameter. This can gets exacerbated when multiple parameters are present, each *combination* of lengths will create its own plan

There are possible problems with other types too, but strings are the most notorious culprits. Again, read the linked article, is highly relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The type is figured out based on the data type of the parameter value that is passed so the SqlParameter constructor.

You can find more info at this link [Configuring Parameters and Parameter Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Go to the "Specifying Parameter Data Types" section.